# find_by doesn't work with passed params item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Why this works?

```
class TransfersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @receiver = Wallet.find_by(number: "e27690b243dc249638b202c930dc022f")
    @sender = Wallet.find_by(number: "3e6c234504e407309d7d91e67f65f5fb")
    render :json => {:receiver => @receiver, :sender => @sender, :params => params}
end
end
```

Output of code above is

```
{"receiver":{"id":1,"owner":1,"number":"e27690b243dc249638b202c930dc022f","money":100,"status":0,"reason":null,"created_at":"2018-08-07T13:46:52.015Z","updated_at":"2018-08-07T13:46:52.015Z"},"sender":{"id":2,"owner":1,"number":"3e6c234504e407309d7d91e67f65f5fb","money":100,"status":0,"reason":null,"created_at":"2018-08-07T13:56:22.097Z","updated_at":"2018-08-07T13:56:22.097Z"},"params":{"utf8":"✓","authenticity_token":"9xlWBswszN6cZSYFeA24TEMDfJheiw+0ZLObdFRw/SYVT0mwDlJu2XMYktvnF0X+n+7uUX8G7iFd07ndNa98Vg==","transfer":{"sender":"e27690b243dc249638b202c930dc022f","receiver":"3e6c234504e407309d7d91e67f65f5fb","summa":"5","comment":"dfhdhfdhf"},"commit":"Отправить","controller":"transfers","action":"create"}}
```

But this doesn't? Receiver and sender objects are both null

```
class TransfersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @receiver = Wallet.find_by(number: params['receiver'])
    @sender = Wallet.find_by(number: params['sender'])
    return :json => {:receiver => @receiver, :sender => @sender, :params => params}
end
end
```

JSON output is

```
{"receiver":null,"sender":null,"params":{"utf8":"✓","authenticity_token":"9xlWBswszN6cZSYFeA24TEMDfJheiw+0ZLObdFRw/SYVT0mwDlJu2XMYktvnF0X+n+7uUX8G7iFd07ndNa98Vg==","transfer":{"sender":"e27690b243dc249638b202c930dc022f","receiver":"3e6c234504e407309d7d91e67f65f5fb","summa":"5","comment":"dfhdhfdhf"},"commit":"Отправить","controller":"transfers","action":"create"}}
```

Comment: Please add request param to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your identifiers are nested below `:transfer` in your `params`.

Try this instead:

```
@receiver = Wallet.find_by(number: params['transfer']['receiver'])
@sender = Wallet.find_by(number: params['transfer']['sender'])
```